# Docker copy: failed to compute cache key/error from sender

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a Docker image from a Dockerfile, and while doing this, I encounter following error with the COPY steps:

`failed to compute cache key: not found: not found` when using relative paths, and
`error from sender: Create file .......\Temp\empty-dir347165903\C:: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect` when using absolute ones

The exact command I'm trying is COPY main.py ./
Important notes would be there is no .dockerignore file whatsoever, no container is set and both main.py and Dockerfile are located in the same directory

Here's what the Dockerfile itself looks like:

```sh
From public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY main.py ./
RUN mkdir chrome
RUN curl -SL (chromedriver link here) > chromedriver.zip
RUN unzip chromedriver.zip -d chrome/
RUN rm chromedriver.zip
```

Comment: What's the actual `docker build` command you're running?  Should that Dockerfile have a default `CMD` to run?  Should you be setting a `WORKDIR` other than the image's root directory?

Comment: The command I'm running is docker build - < Dockerfile; the default ```CMD``` is actually in the Dockerfile, I just forgot to include it, that would be CMD ["main.main"]. And the image's root directory should do the trick, so I'm not planning on changing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The command I'm running is `docker build - < Dockerfile`

This syntax is only valid if your build doesn't use the context. The `docker build` command expects one argument, and that's not the Dockerfile, rather it's the build context. Typically it's a directory, could be a remote git repo, or you can pass a tar file of the directory on stdin with the `-` syntax. There is an exception for passing a Dockerfile instead of the build context, but when this is done, you can't have any COPY or ADD steps that pull files from the build context. Instead, you almost certainly want:

```
docker build .
```

To perform the build using the current directory as your build context, which also contains the Dockerfile. And after that, you'll likely want to add a tag to your resulting image:

```
docker build -t your-image:latest .
```

(Thanks to to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) for the pointer to the [Dockerfile as input](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files) syntax.)

Comment: It [should be syntactically valid to pass only the Dockerfile on stdin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files) but the build context won't have any other files and you won't be able to `COPY` anything into the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze no matter how long I do this, I'm still learning new stuff all the time. Thanks for that pointer!